# Evalute this limit ($x$ tends to $0$) $|x|^{\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}
|x|^{\sin x}
$$

my approach:-
Let $L = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}  |x|^{\sin x}$
$$
\ln L = \lim_{x\to0} (\sin x)\ln|x|
$$
that's it...
please help me

thanks in advance

answer to this problem is 1
Also I'm new here and Idk how to write in mathematical notation sorry.
I'll learn it soon.

Comment: Recall that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)'s a tutorial on typesetting.

Comment: @AndrewChin thank you so much...

Comment: @TitoEliatron Yup got it also thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0} |x|^{\sin x}= \exp[\lim_{x \to 0} \sin x \log |x|] =\exp[\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln |x|}{\csc x}]$$
Apply L'Hospital, to get
$$L=\exp[\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\theta(x)/|x|}{-\cot x \csc x}]=\exp[\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\theta(x)\sin^2 x}{|x| \cos x}]=\exp[\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-\theta(x)\sin x}{|x|} \tan x]=\exp[0]=1. $$
Here $\theta(x>0)=1, \theta(x<0)=-1, \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$ \sin x \cdot\ln |x|= \frac{\sin x}{x} \cdot \frac{\ln |x|}{\frac{1}{x}}.$$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: yes i can proceed but on solving it further the answer will come out to be 0 but it is given 1 in my textbook. Is there something to do with mod?

Comment: The answer in your textbook iswrong.

Comment: @KartikeyaChauhan $0$ yes, but first thing you did was taking $\ln$, so you need to say $\exp(0)$, so you get $1$.

Comment: @Coolwater lmao im so dumb holy shit